# ¿Como tomar el index, de las rows visibles en un DataGrid WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

estoy trabajando con WPF, y no encuentro una manera de tomar el index de las filas visibles de un datagrid.
Estoy trabajando con MVVM... muchas gracias a quien me pueda dar una mano!

Comment: Tu pregunta es un tanto ambigua, no entiendo a que te refieres específicamente con "tomar el index", pero imagino que, si usas MVVM, el ItemsSource del DataGrid es un objeto en el ViewModel, por lo tanto hay que ver que objeto es, una Lista, una DataTable, etc.

Dependiendo del objeto deberías poder tomar el index de ese objeto directamente y no del DataGrid.

Por favor se más específico con tu pregunta y con gusto te ayudaremos. Define como quieres usar el index, para que ó como aplicarás ese dato, entonces será más fácil.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por comentar, mi duda es, ¿como puedo saber que items en un datagrid son visibles? me explico mejor, tengo un datagrid con un items source de mil datos, pero yo no solicito conocer los mil datos solo solicito conocer los datos en el datagrid que son visibles para el usuario en ese momento del runtime... No se si me explicaciòn quedò algo mas clara... Muchas gracias con lo que me pueda ayudar!

Comment: Entiendo que los items no estarán filtrados, solo quieres saber lo que está en pantalla en el momento, pues, solo hay 1 forma desde mi punto de vista pero rompe el patrón mvvm un poco.. lo dejaré como respuesta si te sirve.
Un saludo.

Comment: He añadido como 2da respuesta el modo 100% MVVM para que pruebes y puedan (tu y los demás que vean) comparar ambas formas y añadir sus comentarios y correcciones constructivas.

Answer (score 0):

No veo una forma de hacerlo sin romper en algo el esquema MVVM por el simple hecho de que el ViewModel no debería ver el DataGrid, pero basado en algunos artículos se puede hacer de este modo:

Primero: Requieres este ExtensionMethod:

```
public static T GetVisualChild<T>(this Visual referenceVisual) where T : Visual
{
    Visual child = null;
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(referenceVisual); i++)
    {
        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(referenceVisual, i) as Visual;
        if (child != null && child is T)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (child != null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return child as T;
}
```

Ahora bien, como dije, hay que romper un poco el MVVM, y aquí es donde:
En el codeBehind de tu vista llama al ViewModel

Crea la Property

```
private MyViewModel _myUsedVM;
public MyViewModel MyUsedVM
{
    get { return _myUsedVM; }
    set { _myUsedVM= value; }
}
```

y luego defines el ViewModel en el constructor llamándolo a través de su Key (nombre que le das y que usas para asignar el DataContext en la vista):

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource MyVM}"/>


//El constructor del archivo .cs de tu vista, 
//OJO!! No crees una nueva instancia!! se llama la que ya existe
public MyView()
{
    MyUsedVM= (MyViewModel)FindResource("MyVM"); //x:Key
}
```

Luego, al evento LOADED del DataGrid tienes que asignarle el codigo que enlazará el extensionMethod al control

```
private void dg_items_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollViewer scrollViewer = dg_items.GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(); //Extension method
            if (scrollViewer != null)
            {
                ScrollBar scrollBar = scrollViewer.Template.FindName("PART_VerticalScrollBar", scrollViewer) as ScrollBar;
                if (scrollBar != null)
                {
                    scrollBar.ValueChanged += delegate
                    {
                        double PrimerIndexVisible = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
                        double TotalElementosVisibles = scrollViewer.ViewportHeight;
                        MyUsedVM.SaberLoQueEstoyViendo(PrimerIndexVisible, TotalElementosVisibles);
                    };
                }
            }
        }
```

Finalmente en el ViewModel haces un método público que reciba ambos datos, el index y el total que son doubles:

```
public void SaberLoQueEstoyViendo(double primerIndex, double totalItems)
{
    //Aquí ya sabes cual es el primer item que se ve en la lista y cuantos hay visibles
}
```

Y eso es todo, no es tan difícil.

**YA SÉ** que esto rompe un poco el patrón MVVM pero no veo como lograr lo que quieres sin hacerlo ya que lo que quieres es una función de la vista, no del viewModel, si sabes como controlar eventos de controles en el ViewModel lo podrás lograr sin romper el MVVM pero yo no sé hacerlo.

Espero te ayude a salir del paso, ya lo probé y funciona.
Un saludo!!

Answer (score 0):

[MODO FULL MVVM]
Este modo hace uso del namespace System.Windows.Interactivity para controlar eventos en el ViewModel.

**Paso 1)** 
Agregar referencia a System.Windows.Interactivity

**Paso 2)**
Agregar el namespace en la ventana donde está el DataGrid xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity

```
<Window x:Class="GiaGenesis.Views.Dialogs.SendCheckListGestorDialog"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:GiaGenesis.ViewModels"....
```

**Paso 3)**
Añadir este método de extensión en tu clase estática de extensiones

```
public static T GetVisualChild<T>(this Visual referenceVisual) where T : Visual
{
    Visual child = null;
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(referenceVisual); i++)
    {
        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(referenceVisual, i) as Visual;
        if (child != null && child is T)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (child != null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return child as T;
}
```

**Paso 4)**
Crea un ICommand en tu ViewModel que usarás para bindear el DataGrid al método de extensión

```
//Declaración del ICommand
private ICommand _bindCommand;
public ICommand BindCommand
{
    get { return _bindCommand; }
    set { _bindCommand = value; }
}
```

Lo defines en el constructor para que al lanzarse llame al método que hará el link con el método de extensión

```
//Constructor
public DemoViewModel()
{
    //Para enlazar el datagrid al metodo
    BindCommand = new ParamCommand(new Action<object>(BindMethod));
    //botón para ver los datos
    //ViewCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(SaberLoQueEstoyViendo));
}
```

El método:

```
//El método para bindear el datagrid al metodo
private void BindMethod(object obj) 
{
    DataGrid datagrid = (DataGrid)obj;
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = datagrid.GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(); //Extension method
    if (scrollViewer != null)
    {
        ScrollBar scrollBar = scrollViewer.Template.FindName("PART_VerticalScrollBar", scrollViewer) as ScrollBar;
        if (scrollBar != null)
        {
            //cada vez que muevas el scroll esto se ejecutará
            scrollBar.ValueChanged += delegate
            {
                double PrimerIndexVisible = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
                double TotalElementosVisibles = scrollViewer.ViewportHeight;
                //opcional: mando la info a un método que muestra os valores en un control de lista mediante una colección en el mismo viewmodel
                SaberLoQueEstoyViendo(PrimerIndexVisible, TotalElementosVisibles);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Esto es opcional, yo veo la info en un litbox, pero puedes omitir este metodo y usar un botón para llamar a la info guardando las variables PrimerIndexVisible  y TotalElementosVisibles a nivel de clase:

```
//Y el método que muestra el index y el total de indexs (items) que se ven
public void SaberLoQueEstoyViendo(double primerIndex, double totalItems)
{
    //Log es una ObservableColection de strings bindeada a un ListBox
    Log.Add("-> " + primerIndex + " : " + totalItems);
    //Lo mismo pero por consola
    Console.WriteLine("-> " + primerIndex + " : " + totalItems); //Esto lo tengo en un listbox, se actualiza solo
    RaisePropertyChanged("Log");
}
```

**Paso 5)**
Define tu DataGrid de este modo:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MiTablaSourceView}" Margin="5,50,5.4,99.8">
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
   <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding BindCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
  </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

Y listo, de este modo tienes lo que quieres sin usar el .cs del la vista.
Dejo ambas formas como respuestas independientes para que vean las similitudes en el control del código.

Un saludo.

PS: La clase ParamCommand es lo mismo que RelayCommand con parámetro:

```
public class ParamCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _action;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public ParamCommand(Action<object> action)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = () => true;
    }

    public ParamCommand(Action<object> action, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this._canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            bool result = this._canExecute.Invoke();
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                _action(parameter);
            }
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

}
```